# Resolve linux PC name from android

Tags: android, linux, dns

I'm using Apache to host an internal web, from windows PC if I write the PC name that host the web I access, but if i write the PC name in a device with android , I can't access.
I have been reading but I can't find a solution for this issue.

Comment: What's the output of `$ adb shell getprop | grep dns`

Answer (score 1):

You are able to access this web site of yours from a PC, simply by accessing it name because your PC and the PC that hold the Apache service are on the same network (or even the same PC). you android device on the other hand will not be usually connected to your network. And Even if it is connected using Wireless you still need to make configuration in order this to work.

This is why you can't access it this way.

Comment: is in the same network, the problem is that android don't resolve the pc name, do you know how can i configure this in android ?

Comment: @Diegote92 why not use your PC's IP address instead?

Comment: because the pc that host the web does not have static ip, and i can't configure.

Comment: if use the current ip i success successfully access, but it's very important to my web to not configure a static ip

Comment: I may be wrong but for some reason I have a filling that this is not possible as Linux (which android based on) can't translate IP address to windows PC name as they don't use the same DNS service. and I think you need manually edit the file inside the system for this translation. I am not a Linux expert so I have no idea how its done.